# Getting validation error messages on register page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a login page `http://localhost/register` the register method displays the register page. I am posting the data and validating it in this way

```
$rules = array(
          'telephone' => 'required',
          'theemail' => 'required',
          'fullnames' => 'required',
          'profilepicture' => 'required',
          'password' => 'required',
          'confirm-password' => 'required'
               );

      $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
      if ($validator->fails()) {
          $messages = $validator->messages();
          return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
      }
```

I used the method above to validate a form but when i try the above code, it seems not to validate. My last app was simplistic and the form names were also the column names in the database.

In my case, the array

```
$rules = array(
              'telephone' => 'required',
              'theemail' => 'required',
              'fullnames' => 'required',
              'profilepicture' => 'required',
              'password' => 'required',
              'confirm-password' => 'required'
                   );
```

does not contain names of columns. Must the rules contain the column names of the table i am writing to?.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
          'telephone' => 'required',
          'theemail' => 'required',
          'fullnames' => 'required',
          'profilepicture' => 'required',
          'password' => 'required',
          'confirm-password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store the blog post...
    }
}
```

Comment: @GeoffreyIsle, did you try my answer?

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 Yes i did. The problem is much more complicated than i thought. Has to do with Route groups.

Comment: paste us the entire of the register file and route file. also, you can test if the validator work by using  `dd($validator->fails())`

Comment: I finally managed to have it fixed. I had Start session in middleware and middlewareGroups. I deleted the group one and things are working as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to match the column name in the $rule array with the other in the DB table, and if you mean the validation error doesn't appear, then you have to put this in the blade file which you want to show in.

```
@if(!empty($errors))
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

of course you have to add the needed classes